# Forcing escaped characters when writing to XML

Tags: java, xml, escaping

I'm using org.w3c and javax.xml.parsers in Java for reading and writing xml files.
When I read an xml file, the 
 escaped line breaks will be replaced by real line breaks. When I write the content back to the file, I loose escaping and the content of the file will change unintentionally.
so

```
<somenode>First line.&#10;Second line</somenode>
```

will be replaced by:

```
<somenode>First line.
Second line.</somenode>
```

Before writing xml content back to disk I tried:

```
String content = node.getTextContent().replace("\n","&#10;");
node.setTextContent(content);
```

Of course it does not work, it will be escaped to &amp;#10; in the file.

**I do not want to litter the file with CDATA tags!**

What I want to do is legal XML output so there has to be a way to do it.

Thanks in advance for any ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it by setting the following property for the JAXB Marshaller:

marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "Unicode");